# OpenCV Python Line following Code Low FPS

Tags: python

I tried various ways but i am still getting apx 2-3 fps.

```
import cv2
```

import numpy as np

```html
import cv2
import numpy as np

##cap = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\efeongan\\Desktop\\PYTHOn_OPENCV\\linetest.mp4')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('C:\\Users\\efeongan\\Desktop\\PYTHOn_OPENCV\\linetest.mp4')
while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    lowbg = np.array([0,0,0])
    highbg = np.array([50, 50, 50])
    kernel = np.ones([10, 10], np.uint8)
    mask = cv2.inRange(frame, lowbg, highbg)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(gray, gray, mask = mask)
    dilation = cv2.dilate(res, kernel, iterations = 1)
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(dilation,rho=0.02,theta=np.pi/500, threshold=100,lines=np.array([]), minLineLength= 0)
    a,b,c = lines.shape
    if lines[1][0][0] > 240:
        diff = lines[1][0][0] - 240
        print(diff)
    if lines[1][0][0] < 240:
        diff = 220 - lines[1][0][0]
        print(diff)
    for i in range(a):
        cv2.line(dilation, (lines[i][0][0], lines[i][0][1]), (lines[i][0][2], lines[i][0][3]), (255, 255, 255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.line(frame, (240, 800), (240 + diff, 800), (255,0,0),10)
    cv2.putText(frame,str(diff),(240 + diff,800), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, 255)
    print("x", lines[1][0][0], cnts)
    cv2.imshow('raw', frame)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if k == 27:
        brak
cv2.desrtroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do try using a lower frame resolution. You can experiment with smaller resolutions and see how the accuracy decreases with decreasing resolution, and find a trade-off.

Another possibility is to process only a selected region of each frame. Suppose you find the line to follow in one region of the image. You can assume that the location of the line does not change much in the next frame, and process only the region around this line.